# Stored procedure call gives an error PLS-00306 ORA-06550

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in Oracle which has some parameters and I am calling it from C# (http handler) and sometime getting an exception .

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROC_ADD_...'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I know that the meaning of wrong number or type. It means I am not providing values in all the parameters of the procedure call.

My question is this I have used the `string.trim()` function in every parameter value as follows

So it should give the error or `object reference` or I am wrong somewhere.

```
var prm = new OracleParameter[8];
prm[0] = Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("IP_ACTION", OracleType.VarChar, 20));
prm[0].Value = pobjCustomerProps.Action.Trim();
prm[1] = Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("IOP_CUSTOMER_UID", OracleType.VarChar, 30));
prm[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
prm[1].Value = pobjCustomerProps.CustomerID.Trim();

prm[2] = Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("IP_MOBILE_NO", OracleType.VarChar, 50));
prm[2].Value = objEncryption.Encrypt(pobjCustomerProps.MobileNo.Trim());
prm[3] = Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("IP_CUSTOMER_NAME", OracleType.VarChar, 200));
prm[3].Value = pobjCustomerProps.CustomerName==""? "": objEncryption.Encrypt(pobjCustomerProps.CustomerName.Trim());

 prm[4] = Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("IP_EMAILID", OracleType.VarChar, 500));
 prm[4].Value = pobjCustomerProps.EmailID == "" ? "" : objEncryption.Encrypt(pobjCustomerProps.EmailID.Trim());

 prm[5] = Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("IP_MODEL_CODE", OracleType.VarChar, 10));
 prm[5].Value = pobjCustomerProps.ModelCode.Trim();

 prm[6] = Command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("IP_USER_UID", OracleType.VarChar, 10));
 prm[6].Value = pobjCustomerProps.UserUID.Trim();

var lobjparamErrorCode = new OracleParameter("OP_ERROR_CODE", OracleType.Number) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
prm[7] = Command.Parameters.Add(lobjparamErrorCode);
```

and here is my sp definition

```
 PROCEDURE PROC_ADD_DETAILS_V1
(
    IP_ACTION IN VARCHAR2,
    IOP_CUSTOMER_UID IN OUT DIGICALL.CUSTOMER_DTL.CUSTOMER_UID%TYPE,
    IP_MOBILE_NO IN DIGICALL.CUSTOMER_DTL.MOBILE_NO%TYPE,
    IP_CUSTOMER_NAME IN DIGICALL.CUSTOMER_DTL.CUSTOMER_NAME%TYPE,
    IP_EMAILID IN DIGICALL.CUSTOMER_DTL.EMAIL_ID%TYPE,
    IP_MODEL_CODE IN  DIGICALL.CUSTOMER_DTL.MODEL_CODE%TYPE,
    IP_USER_UID IN DIGICALL.CUSTOMER_DTL.USER_UID%TYPE,
    OP_ERROR_CODE OUT NUMBER        
)
```

Comment: Could you post your SP definition?

Comment: I have edited my question with sq definition. Inside this i am calling different sp on basis of some condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things that can go wrong:

- You can have a wrong number of parameters. Seems to be okay in your case.
- You can have a wrong type of parameter (regarding in/out, regarding data type). Input/output seems to be okay in your case. The data type cannot be derived from your description because the stored procedure definition refers to some other object.
- You can provide the arguments in the wrong order (and thus have a wrong type). Note that by default parameters are bound by position even though you have given a name to each parameter. It partly depends on whether you use ODP.NET or the System.Data.OracleClient classes. It doesn't seem to be the problem in your case.
- It could be that your CommandText doesn't match the parameters. It's missing in your question so we can't tell.

`String.trim()` certainly isn't the problem.

Comment: I am using System.Data.OraclecClient. Is it possible that the procedure which i am using inside the procedure "PROC_ADD_DETAILS_V1" is causing the problem.

Comment: About String.trim() I wanted to say that if any on of parameter value is null then it will raise an exception before calling the procedure like "object reference not set to object"

Comment: It's unlikely that a procedure within PROC_ADD_DETAILS_V1 is causing the problem (unless it's called with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and it's name starts with "PROC_ADD_" as well). Please add more code that includes the creation of the OracleCommand instance and its execution, and add the definition of DIGICALL.CUSTOMER_DTL so we can understand the involved data types.

Comment: I got the solution I had checked my code and in a condition the one of the parameter value was "null".

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error and it was a complete red herring.

[image]

Oracle client 11.2 and 9.2 were both installed. x64 bit server with a x86 application.

The problem was resolved by uninstalling 11.2 and changing a connection string to use **msdaora.1** instead of **OraOLEDB.Oracle.1**.

Alex Keh - Product Manager-Oracle explains why this works: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2491412

<sub>Hope this saves someone else a few locks of hair and days of frustration.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but I needed to change my connection string to include

> providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"

instead of

> providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"